# how to resize array by 50%

Tags: arrays, hash

I'm trying to resize my array by 50% and then rehash. I currently have it doubling by array size and then rehashing, but I'm not sure how to increase by 50% (vs 100%).

Here is my part of my code:

```
private int hashFunction(int value) {
    return Math.abs(value) % elementData.length;
}

private double loadFactor() {
    return (double) size / elementData.length;
}

// Resizes the hash table to twice its former size.
private void rehash() {
    // replace element data array with a larger empty version
    HashEntry[] oldElementData = elementData;
    elementData = new HashEntry[2 * oldElementData.length];
    size = 0;

    // re-add all of the old data into the new array
    for (int i = 0; i < oldElementData.length; i++) {
        HashEntry current = oldElementData[i];
        while (current != null) {
            add(current.data);
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
}
```

How would I change my rehash() method to increase by 50%?

I'm assuming I need to cast as int somewhere but I cannot get it to work. I want to use an Array and not an ArrayList.

Comment: You should be careful with `Math.abs(value)`, that's not always positive.

Comment: Would Integer.parseInt(value) be a better option? What other options could I use?

Comment: `parseInt` is not an option at all, but `value & Integer.MAX_VALUE` or `value >>> 1` will make it definitely non-negative. In Java9 you could use `Integer.remainderUnsigned` to avoid having to throw away a bit from the hash at all. Or an other option: `if (value < 0) value ^= -1;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Couldn't you just change the line

```
elementData = new HashEntry[2 * oldElementData.length];
```

to something like this:

```
elementData = new HashEntry[(int)increase * oldElementData.length];
```

where `increase` is whatever percent increase you want.  So if you wanted a fifty percent increase in size, you would use 1.5.

Comment: You're missing some parentheses there